# Целочисленное переполнение

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* Целочисленное переполнение */
/* Битность определяет диапазон допустимых значений */

int main()
{
    uint8_t byte = 255; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 8 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до 255*/
    uint16_t byte_2 = 65535; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 16 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до 65535 */
    uint32_t byte_4 = 4294967295; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 32 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до  4294967295*/
    uint64_t byte_8 = 18446744073709551615; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 64 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до  18446744073709551615 */
    /* Байт битность */
    printf("Value of byte = %d\n", byte);
    printf("Value of byte = %d\n", byte += 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 2 байта битность 16*/
    printf("Value of byte_2 = %d\n", byte_2);
    printf("Value of byte_2 = %d\n", byte_2 += 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 4 байта битность 32 */
    printf("Value of byte_4 = %d\n", byte_4);
    printf("Value of byte_4 = %d\n", byte_4 += 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 8 байт биность 64 */
    printf("Value of byte_8 = %d\n", byte_8);
    printf("Value of byte_8 = %d\n", byte_8 += 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");

}
```

Здравствуйте у меня есть вопрос касаемо целочисленного переполнения. В этой программе я хотел проверить как происходит целочисленное переполнение . Я использую библиотеку inttypes .
Первый вопрос почему компилятор выдает следующие предупреждение:

**warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned**

**warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]|**

**warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]|**

Второй вопрос почему при запуске программы значение byte_4 функция printf выводит -1 вместо  4294967295 при том если переменная беззнаковая и является 32 битная. Я хотел чтобы она вывела сначала 4294967295 .

Третий вопрос почему при запуске программы значение byte_8 функция printf выводит -1 вместо  18446744073709551615 при том если переменная беззнаковая и является 64 битная. Я хотел чтобы она вывела сначала 18446744073709551615.

Comment: Потому что `%d` выводит целочисленную переменную со знаком. подробнее [`man printf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). Так же вам на помошь придет [`#include <inttypes.h>`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h)

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/2Pwhgg0IC

Comment: Понял спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил нужно было всего лишь поменять спецификаторы формата

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* Целочисленное переполнение */
/* Битность определяет диапазон допустимых значений */

int main()
{
    uint8_t byte = 255; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 8 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до +255*/
    uint16_t byte_2 = 65535; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 16 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до +65535 */
    uint32_t byte_4 = 4294967295; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 32 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до  +4294967296*/
    uint64_t byte_8 = 18446744073709551615; /* беззнаковый тип занимат 64 бит в памяти диапазон допустимых значений о 0 до +18446744073709551616 */
    /* Байт битность */
    printf("Value of byte = %hhu\n" , byte);
    printf("Value of byte = %hhu\n", byte += 1);
    printf("Value of byte = %hhu\n", byte -= 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 2 байта битность 16*/
    printf("Value of byte_2 = %hu\n", byte_2);
    printf("Value of byte_2 = %hu\n", byte_2 += 1);
    printf("Value of byte_2 = %hu\n", byte_2 -= 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 4 байта битность 32 */
    printf("Value of byte_4 = %u\n", byte_4);
    printf("Value of byte_4 = %u\n", byte_4 += 1);
    printf("Value of byte_4 = %u\n", byte_4 -= 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    /* 8 байт битность 64 */
    printf("Value of byte_8 = %llu\n", byte_8);
    printf("Value of byte_8 = %llu\n", byte_8 += 1);
    printf("Value of byte_8 = %llu\n", byte_8 -= 1);
    printf("\n\n\n");

}
```

Comment: Спецификаторы преобразования `hhu`, `hu`, `u`, `llu` предназначены для вывода значений типа `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int` и `unsigned long long` соответственно. Использование данных спецификаторов преобразования для вывода значений типа `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` и `uint64_t` _может_ вызывать неопределённое поведение. Следует использовать специальные форматные константы из заголовочного файла `<inttypes.h>`: `PRIu8`, `PRIu16`, `PRIu32`, `PRIu64`: [`printf("%" PRIu8 "\n",  byte)`](https://rextester.com/SDOSFC9900).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer