# преждевременное переполнение long long

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
unsigned long long u = 3000000000;
printf("%d\n", u);
```

выдает -1294967296, хотя должен в себя вмещать 18446744073709551615

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-format-an-unsigned-long-long-int-using-printf

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Целочисленное переполнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1390912/%d0%a6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте

```
printf("%llu\n", u);
```

и посмотрите, [что получится](https://ideone.com/DhqvIm).

Вы просто используете не тот формат...